# How to define own model using Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have 2000+ training images(of custom farm structures) and I want to define my own model using Tensorflow. I researched (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md). This is a very high-level documentation. Can anyone help me on how to go about doing this?